# How do I (Can I) configure AWS SNS HTTP Request Timeout?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-sns

I'm sorry. This seems like a simple question, but I can't find the answer anywhere.

How do I configure the default http request timeout for an AWS SNS Topic.  Ideally, I'd like to do this via the Java API (v1.11), but if I have to set it manually via the console, that's fine, too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about the timeout for SNS to publish to the HTTP subscriber endpoint, it's hardcoded at 15 seconds: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-http-https-endpoint-as-subscriber.html